# How to do "only one TABLE column" responsible for drag and drop? ( touch-punch )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In a table with the drag-and-drop option.

**How do I get only one column to be responsible for drag and drop?**

[image]

Because all columns currently have the ability to drag and drop, I want only one column to have this property.

**JAVASCRIPT AND JQUERY**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.2/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>


<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#sortable").sortable();
        $("#sortable").disableSelection();

    });

</script>
```

**HTML - TABLE DRAG DROP (touch-punch)**

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Drag Button
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Number
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Description
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody id="sortable">
                <tr>
                    <td class="ui-state-default drag-handler" data-taskid="1"></td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Description item 1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="ui-state-default drag-handler" data-taskid="2"></td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>Description item 2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="ui-state-default drag-handler" data-taskid="3"></td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>Description item 3</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

**CSS**

```
<style class="cp-pen-styles">
            body {
                font-size: 14px;
            }
            .drag-handler {
                width: 8em;
                position: relative;
                background-color: #E4E6EB;
                background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #E4E6EB, #E4E6EB 2px, #fff 2px, #fff 4px, #E4E6EB 4px, #E4E6EB 9px, #fff 9px, #fff 11px, #E4E6EB 11px, #E4E6EB 16px, #fff 16px, #fff 18px, #E4E6EB 18px, #E4E6EB 22px);
                background-size: 10px 20px; 
                cursor: move;
                border-top: 2px solid #FFF;
                border-bottom: 2px solid #FFF;
            }

            .drag-handler:active {
                background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #bab86c, #bab86c 2px, #fff 2px, #fff 4px, #bab86c 4px, #bab86c 9px, #fff 9px, #fff 11px, #bab86c 11px, #bab86c 16px, #fff 16px, #fff 18px, #bab86c 18px, #bab86c 22px);
                background-size: 10px 20px; 
            }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the handle option. It’s documented @ http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-handle

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#sortable").sortable({
    handle: ".drag-handler"
  });
  $("#sortable").disableSelection();

});
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jakecigar/kmzrcohy/)

Comment: See also this question that I realized, because there is a connection between the questions https://stackoverflow.com/q/51225398/9237561