# How to make jquery scroll functions ui-touch-punch work with responsive div class from bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Table without table-responsive class div works perfectly with the sortable options of api jquery ui,

```
$(document).ready (function () {
    $("#sortable").sortable ({
        scroll: true,
        scrollSensitivity: 20,
        scrollSpeed: 40,
    });
    $("#sortable").disableSelection ();
});

<table class = "table-hover table-striped">
    <tr> <td> many, many lines <td> </tr>
</table>
```

But when we put the  responsiveness option in the table the options described above do not work

```
<div class = "table-responsive">
     <table class = "table-hover table-striped">
              <tr> <td> many, many lines <td> </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

The scroll: true, scrollSensitivity: 20, scrollSpeed: 40 options stop working.

How do these options work together with the div class of resposivity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("# sortable").sortable ({
```

is invalid.
Use

```
$("#sortable").sortable ({
```

Comment: The error you encountered had already fixed in my code in visual studio, and still does not work.

Comment: I tried this as well and nothing works $ (".table-responsive #sortable"). sortable ({I put .table-responsive #sortable and it still does not keep running.

Comment: Update my last fiddle with enough HTML and  CSS to make the table worth scrolling.

Comment: Friend hosted the code in a free hosting to show what is happening - in this link we have the two examples | containing and not containing <div class = "table-responsive"> <table> </ table> </ div> http://cyberlacstest.atwebpages.com/

Comment: That’s not what responsive tables are supposed to do. Don’t use it.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/#responsive-tables